# Is there anyway to use `options` outside of an instance method in rails ActiveSerializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, serialization

I have a serializer that is starting to get database query heavy, but not all of the queries are needed every time the serializer is called. I would like to pass a URL param to the serializer to let it know if a certain association is needed. However, I can't seem to find a way to call `options` unless I am inside of an instead method. Am I going about this the wrong way? Basic example:

`class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    has_many :notes, serializer: UserNotesSerializer if options['include_notes']
end`

EDIT the returned error is:

`` *** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `options' for UserSerializer ``

Second Edit: @options is returning `nil` for some reason, preventing me from accessing the options hash. Is this a known problem? Using version 0.8.1

is something like this possible?

Comment: Try `@options[:include_notes]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@options` doesn't exist at the class-level. Ruby evaluates your serializer class and method definitions first. Then you create an options hash which is passed into a new instance of your serializer class when you render. The method for accessing these options is actually named `instance_options` in later versions of ActiveModel::Serializer.

But, you can still accomplish what you're trying to. The most straightforward way would be to use the `except:` option when rendering. Instead of passing `include_notes: false` you can pass `except: [:notes]` when you don't need the association.